# Adding GeoJSON Data to Google Maps API Hosted Locally

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, geojson

I'm trying to get my geojson data onto a google map. I've been trying various methods within the documentation to get my points to load: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.toGeoJson with no success so far. Basically the map is loading fine, but the points aren't loading at all, so I must be doing something wrong with the importing of the points. Especially because when I add points using their drag and drop interface, it seems to load fine.

The mapping code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Makes the sample page fill the window*/
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        left: 25%;
        padding: 5px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        z-index: 5;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="floating-panel">
        <button onclick="toggleHeatmap()">Toggle Heatmap</button>
        <button onclick="changeGradient()">Change gradient</button>
        <button onclick="changeRadius()">Change radius</button>
        <button onclick="changeOpacity()">Change opacity</button>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 39.742043, lng: -104.991531},
          zoom: 10
        });
      }
      var dataPoints = new google.maps.toGeoJson('map.json');
      google.maps.addGeoJson(dataPoints);
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY_GOES_HERE&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then the geoJSON data:

https://api.myjson.com/bins/k45by

It's in a link to save space, but I will use that GeoJSON data in a local file and run it on a local web server using python's http.server.

Comment: [toGeoJson](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.toGeoJson) **exports** data that has been loaded on the map.  To display GeoJson data use [.addGeoJSON](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.addGeoJson) or [.loadGeoJSON](https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/data#Data.loadGeoJson)  ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/nfqkjpv5/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`loadGeoJson`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#load_geojson) method to get data from a domain or local file. It will use a XMLHTTPRequest to fetch your data and do all the steps to get your data ready for usage.

> Every map has a map.data object, which acts as a data layer for arbitrary geospatial data, including GeoJSON. You can load and display a GeoJSON file by calling the loadGeoJSON() method of the data object. The below example shows how to add a map and load external GeoJSON data.

```
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 39.742043, lng: -104.991531},
      zoom: 10
    });
    map.data.loadGeoJson('https://api.myjson.com/bins/k45by');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It turns out I was loading the GeoJSON data *outside* of the initialization function of the map. I thought it was supposed to import the points separately, but it seems like that's not the case.